# c++11 - Performance difference in pointer checking - smart pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, coding-style

Is there any difference between testing a smart pointer, e.g. shared_ptr, using `operator bool`

```
if (!smart_ptr)
{
    // ...
}
```

and using `operator ==` ?

```
if (smart_ptr == nullptr)
{
    // ...
}
```

I know the difference will be small (if any), but it could also help deciding the coding style at the same time.

Comment: I think with decent compiler the difference will be zero. `if (!smart_ptr)` is more compact and expressive enough, to my opinion.

Comment: I would be surprised if a modern compiler didn't generate the same code for both in an optimised build. (The optimal way is of course to structure your code so you don't need null-checks at all.) Style-wise, both are common. If you work alone, pick one style but stay comfortable with reading the other. If you work in a group, agree on a style and stick to that.

Comment: To reiterate @AntonSavin, if(!ptr) is more idiomatic; it also works the same way with optional<> (which uses the first way of checking as a motivation for adopting a pointer-like syntax in the first place).

Comment: @StefanAtev: Good note about optional<>, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Could someone more experienced please enlighten me on how could I make this question more specific? In my view I asked what's the difference between two approaches on testing a specific entity, I don't know how to improve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In gccv4.8:

```
#include <memory>

bool is_empty(const std::unique_ptr<int>& p) {
  return p == nullptr;
}
```

produces assembly code:

```
is_empty(std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > const&):
    cmpq    $0, (%rdi)
    sete    %al
    ret
```

---

```
#include <memory>

bool is_empty2(const std::unique_ptr<int>& p) {
  return !p;
}
```

produces assembly code:

```
is_empty2(std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > const&):
    cmpq    $0, (%rdi)
    sete    %al
    ret
```

Consequently, it makes no difference in a decent modern compiler.

### [**Live Demo by Jonathan Wakely**](http://goo.gl/O3qYfB)

Comment: As I understand, the asm is just `return 0`...

Comment: Yes, your code has been over-optimized: the gcc compiler has proven that your pointer was never initialized, so it treats it as a constant expression.  Try conditionally initializing it based on `ARGC` or something.

Comment: Fixed: http://goo.gl/O3qYfB -- the two forms are still identical

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks I was trying a more complex example I'll adopt yours